# регулярное выражение вытащить первую картинку из текста

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст, 1402787089_623747558.jpg###2014-06|||1402787103_623748628.jpg###2014-06|||1402787145_623755460.jpg###2014-06|||1402786786_623761193.jpg###2014-06

Помогите составить регулярное выражение, что бы из этого текста можно было выдернуть первую картинку, что бы на выходе мы получили: 1402787089_623747558.jpg

Comment: Попробуйте такое регулярное выражение `^[^#]+`

Comment: Неа не работает

Comment: А текст начинается именно с название картинки или до этого момента есть какие-то символы?

Comment: именно с названия картинки

Comment: Хммм вот ваш пример `https://www.debuggex.com/r/G0Buh1SQHFRJbYPs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$str = '1402787089_623747558.jpg###2014-06|||1402787103_623748628.jpg###2014-06|||1402787145_623755460.jpg###2014-06|||1402786786_623761193.jpg###2014-061402787089_623747558.jpg###2014-06|||1402787103_623748628.jpg###2014-06|||1402787145_623755460.jpg###2014-06|||1402786786_623761193.jpg###2014-06';
preg_match('/\d+_\d+.jpg/', $str, $img);
echo $img[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

Зачем регулярка?

```js
alert("1402787089_623747558.jpg###2014-06|||1402787103_623748628.jpg###2014-06|||1402787145_623755460.jpg###2014-06|||1402786786_623761193.jpg###2014-06"
.split("###")
.shift())
```

Comment: так мне именно на php нужно. И обязательно регуляркой